# Change column value at runtime based on condition in mudblazor

Tags: visual-studio, mudblazor

Here is my mudtable

```
<MudTable Items="Items"  FixedHeader="true" Style="width: 100%; height: calc(100% - 52px);"
          MultiSelection="true" SelectOnRowClick="false" >
    <HeaderContent>
        <MudTh>@ScanRulesPageLocalizer["Name"]</MudTh>
        <MudTh>@ScanRulesPageLocalizer["Rule"]</MudTh>            
    </HeaderContent>
    <RowTemplate>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Name">@context.Name</MudTd>
        <MudTd DataLabel="Rule">
           
            @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(@context.rule))
            {
                "IDX";
            }
            else
            {
                "RX";
            }
        </MudTd>
        
    </RowTemplate>
</MudTable>
```

But this is giving me syntax error

> Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

How to fix this?

Comment: You don't need `@` inside the if the statement, try: `@if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.rule))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `"IDX";` and `"RX";` in the if block are statements with no purpose. If you write the same code in any `.cs` file. You will get the same compiler warning because nothing is being done with that statement. Hence the error,

> CS0201    Only assignment, call, increment, decrement, await, and new object expressions can be used as a statement

```js
<MudTd DataLabel="Rule">
    @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.rule))
    {
        "IDX";
    }
    else
    {
        "RX";
    }
</MudTd>
```

If you're trying to render different cell data based on the condition.
Then you need to either surround the data you want to render in HTML elemenets,

```js
<MudTd DataLabel="Rule">
    @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.rule))
    {
        <div>IDX</div>
    }
    else
    {      
        <div>RX</div>
    }
</MudTd>
```

Or surround it with an `@` symbol to denote that the following statement is a markup string.

```js
<MudTd DataLabel="Rule">
    @if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.rule))
    {
        @("IDX")
    }
    else
    {      
        @("RX")
    }
</MudTd>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is what i was looking. I also managed that in Effects so now i dont need to do in razor file